# Preventing a site-wide double submit

Tags: php, twitter, submit, twitter-oauth, fwrite

I was having a hard time figuring out a good title for this question, so I hope this is clear. I am currently using the TwitterOauth module on one of my sites to post a tweet. While this works, I need to set a limit to the amount of tweets submitted; *just one each hour*.

Note: I do not have the option to use a database. This is paramount for the question.

I have incorporated this as follows, in the PHP file that handles the actual posting to the Twitter API:

```
# Save the timestamp, make sure lastSentTweet exists and is writeable
function saveTimestamp(){
    $myFile = "./lastSentTweet.inc";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    $stringData = '<?php function getLastTweetTimestamp() { return '.time().';}';
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
}

# Include the lastSentTweet time
include('./lastSentTweet.inc');

# Define the delay
define('TWEET_DELAY', 3600);

# Check for the last tweet
if (time() > getLastTweetTimestamp() + TWEET_DELAY) {
    // Posting to Twitter API here
} else {
    die("No.");
}
```

(initial) contents of the `lastSentTweet.inc` file (chmod 777):

```
<?php function getLastTweetTimestamp() { return 1344362207;}
```

The problem is that while this works; it allows for accidental double submits; if multiple users (and the site this script runs on is currently extremely busy) trigger this script, it happens that 2 submits (or more, though this has not occurred yet) to Twitter slip through, instead of just the 1. My first thought is the (although minute) delay in opening, writing and closing the file, but I could be wrong.

Does anyone have an idea what allows for the accidental double submits (and how to fix this)?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that: I can't (added that to the question). Otherwise I would of course ;)

Comment: cant imagine a reason why you cant use a db. php has one built in

Comment: But wouldn't this give me the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting race conditions. You will need to implement [locking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) on your file while you're making changes, but you need to enclose *both* the read (the `include` statement) and the update inside the lock; what is critical is to ensure nobody else (e.g. another HTTP request) is using the file, while you read its current value and then update it with the new timestamp.

This would be fairly ineffective. You have other options which might be available in your PHP installation, here are some:

1. You *can* use a database even if you don't have a database server: [SQLite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)
2. You can store your timestamp in APC and use [`apc_cas()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cas.php) to detect if your last stored timestamp is still current when you update it.

**Update**

Your locking workflow needs to be something like this:

1. Acquire the lock on your stored timestamp. If you're working with files, you need to have the file open for reading *and* writing, and have called `flock()` on it. `flock()` will hang if another process has the file locked, and will return only after it has acquired the lock, at which point other processes attempting to lock the file will hang.
2. Read the stored timestamp from the already locked file.
3. Check if the required time has passed since the stored timestamp.

- *Only* if it has passed, send the tweet and save the current timestamp to the file; otherwise you don't touch the stored timestamp.

4. Release the lock (just closing the file is enough).

This would ensure that no other process would update the timestamp after you have read and tested it but before you have stored the new timestamp.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I will look into both options as soon as I have the time. Thanks again!

Comment: Alas, no APC is available. I will look into SQLite, but can't help being intrigued by this problem. I thought about solving it like this:

if the 'saveTimeStamp' function would return true, and I would include an extra 'if' before sending the tweet: 'if (saveTimeStamp()) { //tweet }' would this perhaps fix it? (Or at least make the window of opportunity smaller?)